# How to send/recieve a simple string programatically to bluetooth enabled device when there is no internet connection

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am developing a native mobile application where I need to pass a string from one device to the another via Bluetooth (assuming both devices are paired up and same application is running on both devices) with out internet connection.

I have been researching on this requirement from the last two days, but couldn't find strong resources to achieve this task. I have followed this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956101/how-to-send-receive-string-via-bluetooth-android-to-another-android-phone) to pursue a solution, but when I run the app with the above code the app crashes while sending the string.

It would be great if someone can give working solutions or shed some light on me to achieve this task.

Comment: what You mean with "no internet connection"? You don´t need an internet connection for a bluetooth transfer....

Comment: Let me be more specific, when there is no internet connection on the user device, I want to pass a string  via Bluetooth as i am sending same string to user device when internet connection is on from server.

Comment: Try Bluetooth Chat tutorials, you can write data via BluetoothSocket.